# How do I place custom widget area after header on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I used the code below to register a widget area in my function.php file for my child theme:

```
// Register our widget areas.
function home_header_widget() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( ' After Header', 'shop-isle' ),
        'id'            =>'after-header-home',
        'description'   => __( 'widget area after header in home page', 'shop-isle' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}


add_action( 'widgets_init', 'home_header_widget' );
```

This made the new widget area show up in the wordpress widgets section. But I have been struggling to create the condition for displaying the widget area after the header in homepage only.

I tried to use this code in functions.php after the above code:

```
// Place the widget area after the header in home page only
add_action ('shop_isle_after_header', 'add_my_widget_area');
function add_my_widget_area() {
  if ( 'is_home'() ) ('dynamic_sidebar') ) {
    dynamic_sidebar('After Header');
  }
}
```

But that only gave me a parsing error. Any help is appreciated, please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and *the errors you have received*. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Thanks Jose, I will do as you've suggested.

Comment: I think something is wrong with this line: `if ( 'is_home'() ) ('dynamic_sidebar') ) {`.